# Put "on the block", "on the line", "on the altar"

Tags: difference, word-difference

As I understand, the block is a chopping block where you can loose your head. Does putting something on the line mean the same, that they are interchangable? I understand that putting on the altar is different in that you trade something for something else, that is, you loose the item put for sure. But what about the on the block and on the line? How different they are: syntactic purely or they have semantic differences as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*On the block* and *on the line* have quite different meanings.

To put something "on the block" may mean to threaten it with execution, but these days it more often means to put it on the auction block—to put it up for sale.

To put something "on the line" usually means to put it at risk of loss or failure: the *line* here is originally the "pass line" on a craps table, where bets are placed. To put something on the line may also mean to make it explicit, but this is more usually expressed by "lay it on the line".

Answer (score 1):

When used in the context you're talking about, "on the block" would always be phrased as "**on the chopping block**". If you said "They're discussing layoffs. My job is on the block" I would have to stop and think about what you meant, but if you said "My job is on the chopping block" I would immediately get the meaning -- your job is one that may be considered for layoffs.

The difference between "**on the chopping block**" and "**on the line**" is a question of control. The things put on the chopping block have no say in it. Management discussing layoffs to save money is a situation out of your control, putting your job on the chopping block. If I'm supporting your proposal, knowing that if it fails we're both fired, then I'm putting my job on the line by supporting you.

Incidentally, "on the altar" is almost always phrased specifically as "____ **sacrificed on the altar of** ____".

(And is not to be confused with "on a pedestal", which means to value something too much.)